# CanMoveRowAtIndexPath is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

Just look at that image (you may need to enlarge it)

In watch pane you see that tableView is null. Doesn't make sense. Under no circumstances tableView is null in `- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

And it isn't really null.

The code:

```
   PO(tableView);
    PO(self.delegate.tvDelegated);
    PO(self.delegate.tvDelegated.dataSource);
    PO(self.delegate.tvDelegated.delegate);
    PO(indexPath);
```

clearly shows taht the tableView is the same with self.delegate.tvDelegated and the data source and delegate of that is self.

```
tableView: <UITableView: 0x1ea4c800; frame = (0 0; 320 367); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1f082f30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f29d8d0>; contentOffset: {-0, 10}>
self.delegate.tvDelegated: <UITableView: 0x1ea4c800; frame = (0 0; 320 367); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1f082f30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f29d8d0>; contentOffset: {-0, 10}>
```

Comment: Is this a debug build or a release build?  What version of Xcode are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW15)

> For the reordering control to appear, you must not only set this
>   property but implement the UITableViewDataSource method
>   tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:. In addition, if the data
>   source implements tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath: to return NO, the
>   reordering control does not appear in that designated row.

Implement

```
- (BOOL) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndex toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndex
```

Comment: your method signature is wrong. The correct one is `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath`